# Representation of Linear Map in Matrix Form

Tags: linear-algebra

In the Matrices section of the book Linear Algebra Done Right, there's a section I'm finding hard to understand. The passage is:

> The $k^{th}$ column of M(T) consists of the scalars needed to write
> $Tv_k$ as a linear combination of ($w_1$,.....,$w_m$):
>
> $Tv_k$ = $\sum^{m}_{j=1} A_{j,k}w_j$

I'm having hard time understanding the summation part. Let for example we have linear map from $\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ of this form.

$T\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ = $\begin{pmatrix}3\\4\end{pmatrix}$ and $T\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ = $\begin{pmatrix}6\\9\end{pmatrix}$.

In this example the matrix $A$ is \begin{pmatrix} 
3 & 6\\ 
4 & 9\\ 
\end{pmatrix}

Then how we are reaching to $Tv_k$ = $\sum^{m}_{j=1} A_{j,k}w_j$ in this example?

Let $T\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$. Now, how will I represent it in terms of

$\sum^{m}_{j=1}A_{j,1}$$w_j$ where $A_{j,1} = \begin{pmatrix} 
3\\ 
4\\ 
\end{pmatrix}$ and $w_j = \begin{pmatrix}3\\4\end{pmatrix}$

Basically, how the *summation* is getting into this portion?
Thanks!

Comment: Is $M(T)$ the matrix of $T$ in the standard basis ?
In your example, this should be the matrix of $T$ in the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Is the section of your book about change of basis ? Is $v_k$ part of a new basis ? In that case, the summation is about $Tv_k$ being expressed in the basis $(w_j)_j$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using for the bases $v_1,v_2$ and $w_1,w_2$ the standard basis $\pmatrix{0\\1}$ and $\pmatrix{1\\0}$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

You calculate the matrix $A$ correctly.

But when you write $w_j=\pmatrix{3\\4}$ I think you are writing nonsense.

What we get (and expect to get) is

$T v_1=A_{11}w_1 +A_{21}w_2$ which is $T\pmatrix{1\\0}=3\pmatrix{1\\0}+4\pmatrix{0\\1}$.

Comment: Yes. Your answer make sense. Thanks! I actually get example from here: https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Linear_Algebra/Book%3A_A_First_Course_in_Linear_Algebra_(Kuttler)/05%3A_Linear_Transformations/5.02%3A_The_Matrix_of_a_Linear_Transformation_I#thm:matrixoflineartransformation

Answer (score 1):

Linear mapping $T:\Bbb R^n\rightarrow\Bbb R^m$ can be represented by the matrix

$A = \left( \begin{array}{cccc} w_1 & w_2 &\ldots & w_n \end{array} \right)$

where $w_i = Tv_i$ is the image (column vector) of basis element $v_i$, where $\Bbb R^n$ has basis $\{v_1,\ldots, v_n\}$.

Then matrix multiplication

$Ax = \left( \begin{array}{cccc} w_1 & w_2 &\ldots & w_n \end{array} \right)\left(\begin{array}{c} x_1 \\\vdots\\ x_n \end{array}\right)$ gives the column vector
$x_1w_1+\ldots,x_nw_n$, which is a linear combination of the columns of $A$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated my question bit more. This might help you what my exact question is. What you have mentioned is correct. But not exactly clears my doubt.